# Could not communicate between 2 ubuntu servers in virtualbox

Tags: 16.04, networking, virtualbox, ssh

I created 2 ubuntu servers with bridge adapters for internal network and internet in network settings.After that I added /etc/network/interfaces to use both network for static ip address.

```
(changed in both servers 110/111)
# The host-only network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.111
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

But it couldnt work, than I changed it manually in ubuntu edit connections page like 192.168.1.110/255.255.255.0/192.168.1.1 than I checked both server with ifconfig.Its worked.

- servername: dodo    192.168.1.110
- servername: test1   192.168.1.111

I pinged both server and its worked.

```
test1@test1-VirtualBox:~/.ssh$ ping 192.168.1.110
PING 192.168.1.110 (192.168.1.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.110: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.287 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.110: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.612 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.110: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.630 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.110: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.314 ms
```

I tried to create ssh connection.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
ssh-keygen
```

I tried to send `id_rsa.pub` to dodo machine .But I got following error.So now I can use ping but I can't use scp or ssh, how can I fix this?

```
test1@test1-VirtualBox:~/.ssh$ scp -v id_rsa.pub dodo@192.168.1.110:/home
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.168.1.110, user dodo, command scp -v -t /home
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.110 [192.168.1.110] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/test1/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test1/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test1/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/test1/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.110:22 as 'dodo'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:9WYCnZbK5pne0+335BObL+IejAjf7dptB3NUv8NzD/Q
debug1: Host '192.168.1.110' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/test1/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/test1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test1/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```